# помогите с urlManager rules на Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня 
return $this->render('about-'.$id);
view файл 7 и оно по запросу выбирает виды. Вопрос в том, что хочу убрать 
domen.com/site/about?id=2 Должна выглядеть domen.com/about/2

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас урл до страницы сейчас действительно такой `domen.com/site/about?id=2`, то попробуйте вписать в rules это правило.

```
'/site/about/<id:.+>' => '/about'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'about/<id:\d+>' => 'site/about'
```